# When is $n\choose k$ a multiple of $n$

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

While working through a question, the solution states that in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime, we have $(u+v)^p=u^p + v^p$ and since $(u+v)^p={p\choose 0}u^pv^0+{p\choose 1}u^{p-1}v+...+{p\choose p}u^0v^p$, I think the solution is implying that ${p\choose i}$ is a multiple of $p$ $\forall i\in \{1,...,p-1\}$. If so, then is this true in general, or only when $p$ is prime.

Comment: $\binom42 = 6$ is the first counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \forall i \in \{1,...,n-1\}\quad  {n\choose i}$ is divisible by $n$ iff $n$ is a prime. Note that if $n$ is not a prime, then let $ n = p m$ where p is a prime. Then $$ {pm \choose p} = \frac{pm!} {p! (p(m-1))!}$$. So both denominator and numerator has p as a factor m times. So all the $p$'s cancel each other and the quotient is not divisible by $pm$.

Answer (score 1):

Since for $n≠ 1,p$ where $p$ is prime,
$$\binom{p}{n} = \frac{p(p-1)…1}{n!(p-n)!} ∈ \mathbb{Z} $$
and none of the factors in the denominator can divide $p$, this means that $p \left| \binom{p}{n}\right.$.

If for example $p = 2q$ where $q>2$ is prime, then

$$\binom{2q}{q} = \frac{2q(2q-1)…1}{(q!)^2} $$
then $q$ appears as a factor precisely 2 times on top and 2 times on the bottom, and none of the other numbers can divide $q$, so we have no hope of $2q  \left| \binom{2q}{n}\right.$ being true.